# Can I query pretty-printed JSON with AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-athena

I have an S3 bucket with thousands of JSON files that were "pretty-printed", meaning they are valid JSON but contain line breaks and indentation in them.

Each JSON file contains a single document, meaning it starts with `{` and ends with `}`.

Example:

```
{
  "id": "0d8147aa-f08f-4b02-aaec-db1af70c2904",
  "customer": {
    "id": "10d55752-9fbc-434c-bcff-f80b55216c07",
    "given_name": "Edward",
    "middle_initial": "M",
    "family_name": "Fielding"
  }
}
```

I created a table like so:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `sales` (
    `id` STRING,
    `customer` STRUCT<
        `id`:STRING,
        `given_name`:STRING,
        `middle_initial`:STRING,
        `family_name`:STRING>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION
  's3://my-bucket/my-folder/'
```

But when I try to run any query, I get:

```
Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}'
```

As an experiment, I grabbed some of the files and removed the line breaks to have each JSON document in a single line, and the problem disappeared.

Is Athena simply incapable of dealing with "pretty-printed" JSON?
Is there a way to configure the SERDE to support this?

In my environment, these files are generated by something that is exceedingly difficult to change.
In any programming language, dealing with files like these is so trivial. I'll be terribly disappointed if the conclusion is that it's not possible to use these files with Athena.

Comment: No. The two JSON SERDE (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json-serde.html) don't support it. Write your data differently to file. They are not meant for human reading but for machines.

Comment: @Theo Yes. I also gave AWS some feedback in relation to the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/parsing-JSON.html

I checked the page again today, and it seems to have been improved. It's now quite clear that it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena does not support pretty printed JSON, and there is no workaround other than reformatting the data into one object per line. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54507266/1109

Comment: In my use case, changing my data is too unpractical and costly. I am now considering writing an S3 Object Lambda to reformat the JSONs when Athena reads them. I'd use an S3 access point for that and make Athena read from it through an S3 bucket alias. Do you see any potential issues with this strategy?